# logs sent from logstash haven't been indexed in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I've written an apache.conf file for logstash as shown below:

```
input 
{
    file {
        path => "E:\ferdowsi-data\data\logs\logs"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
    
}

filter
{
    grok{
        match => {
            "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
        }
    }
    mutate{
        convert => { "bytes" => "integer" }
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        locale => en
        remove_field => "timestamp"
    }
    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
    useragent {
        source => "agent"
        target => "useragent"
    }
}


output
{
    stdout {
        codec => dots
    }

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
    }

}
```

after elasticsearch & kibana setting up, I ran the following command:

```
bin\logstash.bat -f E:\ferdowsi-data\data\apache.conf
```

but I've got this results in cmd:

> Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2
> WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a
> bundled JDK Sending Logstash logs to
> E:/ferdowsi-data/logstash-7.15.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.1/logs
> which is now configured via log4j2.properties
> [2021-11-02T19:34:53,285][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j
> configuration path used is:
> E:\ferdowsi-data\logstash-7.15.1-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.1\config\log4j2.properties
> [2021-11-02T19:34:53,307][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting
> Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.15.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby
> 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15.0.2+7-27 on 15.0.2+7-27 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
> [2021-11-02T19:34:53,532][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal]
> Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line
> options are specified [2021-11-02T19:34:59,861][INFO ][logstash.agent
> ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:01,963][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections]
> Reflections took 254 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 120 keys and 417
> values [2021-11-02T19:35:08,699][INFO
> ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output
> {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch",
> :hosts=>["http://localhost:9200/"]} [2021-11-02T19:35:09,667][INFO
> ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs
> updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:10,034][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
> Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:10,221][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
> Elasticsearch version determined (7.15.1) {:es_version=>7}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:10,228][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
> Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used
> to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:10,425][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
> Configuration is data stream compliant but due backwards compatibility
> Logstash 7.x will not assume writing to a data-stream, default
> behavior will change on Logstash 8.0 (set `data_stream => true/false`
> to disable this warning) [2021-11-02T19:35:10,425][WARN
> ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Configuration is data stream
> compliant but due backwards compatibility Logstash 7.x will not assume
> writing to a data-stream, default behavior will change on Logstash 8.0
> (set `data_stream => true/false` to disable this warning)
> [2021-11-02T19:35:10,517][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
> Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7,
> :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled} [2021-11-02T19:35:11,548][WARN
> ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A
> gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.RubySymbol) has been
> created for key: status. This may result in invalid serialization.  It
> is recommended to log an issue to the responsible
> developer/development team. [2021-11-02T19:35:11,553][WARN
> ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A
> gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.RubySymbol) has been
> created for key: status. This may result in invalid serialization.  It
> is recommended to log an issue to the responsible
> developer/development team. [2021-11-02T19:35:11,595][WARN
> ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge] A gauge
> metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.RubySymbol) has been created for
> key: status. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is
> recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development
> team.
> [2021-11-02T19:35:16,863][ERROR][logstash.filters.geoip.databasemanager]
> Connect to geoip.elastic.co:443 [geoip.elastic.co/104.154.207.153]
> failed: Connect timed out
> {:cause=>org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
> geoip.elastic.co:443 [geoip.elastic.co/104.154.207.153] failed:
> Connect timed out} [2021-11-02T19:35:17,111][INFO
> ][logstash.filters.geoip   ][main] Using geoip database
> {:path=>"E:/ferdowsi-data/logstash-7.15.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.1/data/plugins/filters/geoip/CC/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"} [2021-11-02T19:35:18,035][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main]
> Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4,
> "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50,
> "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500,
> "pipeline.sources"=>["E:/ferdowsi-data/data/apache.conf"],
> :thread=>"#<Thread:0x67262850 run>"} [2021-11-02T19:35:22,350][INFO
> ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution
> initialization time {"seconds"=>4.3} [2021-11-02T19:35:22,683][INFO
> ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one
> based on the "path" setting
> {:sincedb_path=>"E:/ferdowsi-data/logstash-7.15.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.1/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_16641d4dcb06fea1584da5dab1d50d1b",
> :path=>["E:\ferdowsi-data\data\logs\logs"]}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:22,858][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main]
> Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
> [2021-11-02T19:35:23,080][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines
> running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main],
> :non_running_pipelines=>[]} [2021-11-02T19:35:23,090][INFO
> ][filewatch.observingtail
> ][main][66b892a5d2b1ce6637fc3b1583e69a7f7f213fce29afe3cbec145c6ad96b24cf]
> START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections

and unfortunately, nothing have been indexed in elasticsearch. How can i fix it?
My configuration is:

```
Windows 10
elasticsearch 7.15.1
logstash 7.15.1
kibana 7.15.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use backslash in the path option, it is treated as an escape, so logstash is waiting for the file "E:ferdowsi-datadatalogslogs" to be created. Use forward slash or double backslash.

```
path => "E:/ferdowsi-data/data/logs/logs"
```

Comment: do you mean something like this?

bin\\logstash.bat -f E:\\ferdowsi-data\\data\\apache.conf

Comment: Edited to address what I meant

Comment: Thanks! It worked finally!